# Search using textbox from differend table

Tags: c#, mysql

I need to make textboxkeychange search a data from two different table column

public void searchData(string valuetoFind)
{
myconnection.Connection_db();

```
        string query = $"Select a.Date, a.Emp_ID, e.Firstname, e.Lastname, a.Time_In, a.Time_Out " +
            $"from attendance a Inner Join emp_list e ON e.Emp_ID = a.Emp_ID" +
            $"where concat(a.Emp_ID, e.Firstname) LIKE '%{valuetoFind}%'";
        try
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter msda = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, Connection.conn);

            DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
            msda.Fill(dtbl);
            dgvattend.DataSource = dtbl;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I need a search where i can find any data containing the letter i type on a selected column... Please help

Comment: `AND` .........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question could certainly do with improvement as it is really not clear what the problem is.

But it looks like you sql where clause is incorrect.  Conditions in the where clause are combined with the `AND` / `OR` statements.  So you should have

```
where a.Emp_ID LIKE '%valuetoFind%' AND e.Firstname LIKE '%valuetoFind%';
```

Comment: this works on MySqlworkbench but when i run the program, it will keep resulting to error